# Could not autowire FeignClient in service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have a simple API who it uses a FeignClient to call on other api and get an access token. However today i don't understand why my client is null.

Can you explain why on run, my feign client is null ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AppController {

    private final MyService myService = new MyService();
}
```

My Service

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyClient myClient;

  public AccessToken applicationLogin(final LoginParameters loginParameters) {
        return myClient.getAccessToken(loginParameters);
    }
}
```

My client

```
@FeignClient(name = "myClient", url = "https://myurl.com")
public interface MyClient {

    @PostMapping("/auth/login")
    AccessToken getAccessToken(@RequestBody LoginParameters loginParameters);
}
```

Error

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong variable to invoke the method instead of `r2aClient` you should ise myClient

```
public AccessToken applicationLogin(final LoginParameters loginParameters) {
    return myClient.getAccessToken(loginParameters);
}
```

**Edit** based in new changes

I guess the `@EnableFeignClient`  is not able to find the class MyClient, try `@EnableFeignClient(basePackages = "<your package for MyClient>)`

Comment: That was a mistake on copy / paste

Comment: You may accept the answer as well, if it resolved the issue

Comment: No, this is not resolved. That was a bad copy / paste in stackoverflow.. i edited my initial post

Comment: I have updated my answer, if it doesn’t help request you to share the code so I can have a look and get the root cause

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to inject the `Service` in your `Controller`.
You created your Service as a normal Java-class so the `MyClient` is not injected.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AppController {
    @Autowired
    private final MyService myService;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use

```java
new MyService();
```

if use 'new',it will not be managed by spring.
you could check it by

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {
    
    private IMyService iMyService = new MyServiceImpl();
}
```

```java
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements IMyService {

   @Autowired
   private MyMapper myMapper;

  //....

}
```

myMapper will always be null.cuz you create it by new.
by the way,since Spring 4,field injection is not recommended